# Как убрать апплет сети в Gnome 3

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, ubuntu

Как убрать апплет сети? Удалил  network-manager, а его значок в панели остался.  Gnome 3.2 (Mint 12 aka Ubuntu 11.10)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите плагины на https://extensions.gnome.org/ - точно название не скажу, но найдете много чего интересного, добавляющего функциональность и удаляющего некоторые моменты ненужные.

+ используйте поиск по ключевым словам: net, network или remove и вполне вероятно, что-то попадется хорошее.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo aptitude remove nm-applet
```

Comment: В Gnome-3 как-то по-другому